# Show that if $y-x,z-y,x-z\in U$ with $\dim(U)=1$ then one of $x,y,z$ is a convex combination of the other two

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I was given a HW question to:

> Show that if $y-x,z-y,x-z\in U$ are all different with $\dim(U)=1$, then one of
>   $x,y,z$ is a convex combination of the other two.

A note: The setting is that all vectors are in $\mathbb{R^n}$

**My efforts**:

denote $v=y-x$ then $z-y=\alpha v$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$
since every non zero element of $U$ spans it.

note that 
$$
(1+\alpha)v=v+\alpha v=(y-x)+(z-y)=z-x=-(x-z)
$$

thus
$$
x-z=-(1+\alpha)v
$$

thus $x-z$ can be shown to be in $U$ even without the explicit assumption.
Then I tried to discard the use of the redundant data that $x-z\in U$
and just write $v=y-x,z-y=\alpha v$ but I can see how I would get
a convex combination from this.

I would appreciate any help on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a $v$ that spans $U$.
Write $y-x = \alpha_1 v$, $z-y = \alpha_2 v$, $z-x = \alpha_3 v$.  Without loss of generality, suppose that $0 \leq \alpha_2 \leq \alpha_3$.  We then have
$$
y = z - \alpha_2 v = z - \frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_3}(z - x) = \left(1 - \frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_3} \right)z + \frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_3}x
$$
So, $y$ is a linear combination of $x$ and $z$.

Comment: Note: there's a lot going on in that "without loss of generality".  Feel free to ask for clarification